# Problem with angular pipe and directive code introspection

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea

I'm having an issue with my angular code that I can't solve.

I'm using intelliJ as code editor. The project compile and run correctly. All the file *.ts* are ok but I'm having an issue with my *.html*. In a word any directive or pipe is highlighted as an error. For example, the message I receive from my editor is :

*Property ngClass is not provided by any applicable directives nor by div element*

or for the async pipe:

*Missing require() statement*

same story of *ngIf or *ngFor, but as I told you everything compile and run well. I guess is something related with the editor or angular configuration...

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This sounds like the editor to me, honeslty I'm surprised you're using intellij for web development, I'd think you'd be using visual studio code for this as it has all the right extensions and support for it. In your case is most likely the linter.

Comment: Yes..it was intellij problem. Update to last version fix the problem.

Comment: Same problem happening in WebStorm, seems that only Angular 12 projects are affected by this problem, since I have another project with Angular 11 that works perfectly with the IDE, I don't know what's the problem

Comment: @LucaT I'm using Webstorm latest version, but the problem persists